# How do I print the line number of each line in a string?

Tags: ruby, string

If I have a string within `c1`, I can print it in a line by doing:

```
c1.each_line do |line|
  puts line
end
```

I want to give the number of each line with each line like this:

```
c1.each_with_index  do |line, index|
  puts "#{index} #{line}"
end
```

But that doesn't work on a string.

I tried using `$.`. When I do that in the above iterator like so:

```
puts #{$.} #{line}
```

it prints the line number for the last line on each line.

I also tried using `lineno`, but that seems to work only when I load a file, and not when I use a string.

How do I print or access the line number for each line on a string?

Comment: Not what you asked for but you may be interested nonetheless, if you ever wanted all the lines in a file (the one you're actually in) you can add this to your script: `p File.new(__FILE__).each.with_index { |l,i| puts "line #{i+1}: #{l}" };''`. Try it out.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Slightly modifying your code, try this:

```
c1.each_line.with_index do |line, index|
   puts "line: #{index+1}: #{line}"
end
```

This uses with [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) method in Enumerable.

Comment: This is awesome. Never knew about the `with_index` method on Enumerable. I learned something today! Thanks much meng!

Answer (score 8):

Slightly modifying @sagarpandya82's code:

```
c1.each_line.with_index(1) do |line, index|
  puts "line: #{index}: #{line}"
end
```

Comment: This is clever. Thanks for this modification.

Answer (score 3):

```
c1 = "Hey diddle diddle,\nthe cat and the fiddle,\nthe cow jumped\nover the moon.\n"

n = 1.step
  #=> #<Enumerator: 1:step> 
c1.each_line { |line| puts "line: #{n.next}: #{line}" }
  # line: 1: Hey diddle diddle,
  # line: 2: the cat and the fiddle,
  # line: 3: the cow jumped
  # line: 4: over the moon.
```